# Question about the Range of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in a metric space $(X,d_x)$. The sequence is a mapping from the natural numbers to $X$, $f:\mathbb{N} \to X$. We say that the range of a sequence is the range of $f$, i.e. ran$\{x_n\}$ = ran$f$.

Consider the following sequence: $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$. My question is, what is ran$\{x_n\}$? In my notes I have written that ran$\{x_n\} = (0,1]$ which I believe is wrong. Is the point $\frac{9}{10}$, for example, in the range of $\{x_n\}$?

Comment: Yes, the range of the sequence is the set of values of the terms, i.e., $\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$. Since $\frac9{10}$ is not of the form $\frac1n$ for any $n$, it is not in the range of the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The range of the sequence $\{x_n\}$ (using your notation) is the set $\{x_n\mid n\ge 1\}$. In particular, the range of the sequence you mention is $\{1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, \dots \}$.